# Como ler um arquivo .json no module.config() do Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Tenho um arquivo config.json na raiz do meu projeto com algumas informações que podem ser alteradas: caminho de pastas, etc..

Não posso criar constantes (angular.constant) no código, pois como eu disse os valores do arquivo podem ser alterados em produção.

Porém preciso ler esse arquivo no module.config() e não estou conseguindo, como posso fazer isso?

**Preciso de algo parecido com o que faço no Servidor(Node.js)**

```
var options = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(require('path').dirname(require.main.filename) + '/config.json'));
```

Arquivo de configuração:

```
{
  "port": "3000",
  "ipserver": "127.0.0.1",
  "portserver": "3007"
}
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo agora? Poderia mostrar o código que há possui?

Comment: Então amigo, ainda não implementei, estou sem ideias, editei a pergunta e coloquei uma funcionalidade similar que tenho no servidor(node.js), Mas basicamente preciso ler/carregar um arquivo .json no module.config do angular.

Comment: Respondi sua pergunta @Geferson. Javascript não acessa diretamente o disco, você terá que procurar por outras alternativas.

Comment: Não sei quem negativou as respostas, acho que são válidas, só não resolvem complemente o meu problema. alguma ideia adicional?

Comment: Provavelmente porque não entende o que leu, senão teria negativado com comentário. Se puder, poste seu module.config.

Comment: Não fui eu que negativei, portanto não sei a razão. Entretanto a idéia de consumir um recurso em tempo de configuração não é indicada, pois você está misturando dois estágios. Porque não disparar um serviço de inicialização que leia o arquivo `configuracao.json` no método `.run()`? Sua aplicação deve suportar a falta do arquivo graciosamente - por exemplo exibindo uma mensagem de erro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve colocar este arquivo `.json` dentro de uma pasta na `public` e acessá-la usando o `$http`:

```
$http.get("./conf/configuracao.json").success(function(dados, status, headers, config) {
  ...
}).error(function(dados, status, headers, config) {
  ...
});
```

Você pode injetar a dependência com uma solução que não é a ideal mas funciona na maioria dos casos no `.config`:

```
var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $http = initInjector.get('$http');
```

Comment: Sim, eu já havia pensado nessa ideia, mas não é possível injetar $http no module.config.

Comment: @Geferson Você pode tentar usar o `$http` dessa forma `var initInjector = angular.injector(['ng']);
var $http = initInjector.get('$http');`. Já que no `.config` ele pode não ter sido inicializado ainda

Comment: Deu certo! Se puder adicionar na resposta, eu valido ela como correta. muito obrigado.

Comment: @Geferson adicionado

Answer (score 1):

Javascript não tem acesso direto ao disco, isso quer dizer que não existe alguma função que acessa diretamente algum arquivo, como o `fs.readFile` do *node.js* ou File reader do Java. Eu sugiro duas opções:

**HTTP GET**

```
$http.get('/caminho/config.json').then((res)=>{
     var configuracao = res.data;
});
```

Dessa forma é possível carregar o arquivo e ler as propriedades. Então com o resultado aplicar da forma desejada.

**UTLIZAR ALGUM AUTOMATIZADOR**

Como o [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) ou [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) por exemplo.

Comment: Certo, mas como eu injeto $http no module.config ?

Comment: Poste como está seu arquivo com o módulo de configuração.

Comment: Dei um upvote na sua resposta já que ela responde parcialmente o que foi perguntado.

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack :)

Answer (score 1):

Como você mesmo comentou em outra resposta, não é possível usar o `$http` dentro do config. Eu sugiro você utilizar uma requisição ajax com javascript puro.

```
angular.config(config);

config.inject = [...]; // injeção dos seus provider

function config(...) {
  var configAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  configAjax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var json = JSON.parse(configAjax.responseText);
      ... resto de sua configuração
    }
  }

  configAjax.open('GET', 'path/do/json', true);
  configAjax.send();
}
```